# How to make sync function async in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am currently utilizing an excel parser library called `XLSX`

I have to parse large size excel file and the problem is that `XLSX` only supports synchronous `readFile` request. So when multiple `http` requests are made, the `XLSX` reading function blocks the other requests making user experience very bad. I am currently using expressJS as my framework. Is there a way of making the function asynchronous instead of having to change the excel reading library?

Thanks

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you have other parser options besides xlsx.  If you want an async version, try `excel`, it handles xlsx files asynchronously.

Comment: @Paul Thank you. I'll look into that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only know of three choices:

1. Rewrite the XLSX library to use asynchronous I/O.
2. Create a work queue and several child processes and run the XLSX work in child processes only.
3. Pick a different library that uses async I/O.

There is no way to make a function that uses synchronous I/O magically become async without rewriting it or moving it to another process.

Comment: Thanks. the second choice looks to be a good method, otherwise third. Is there anything that I should be aware of if I decide to spawn a new read process every time new request is made?

Comment: @serendipity - You probably want to put a cap on the number of processes you open and use a queue if there isn't a worker process ready.  This prevents a DOS attack by causing you to create too many processes.

Comment: Thanks I'll make sure of that